# How can I know if a page that links to my site is actually indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I want to know if a page that contains links to my site is indexed by Google.

The classic `site:` works for URL like in:

```
fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Râle_de_Platen
```

but not for URL like:

```
http://jcfrog.com/shaarli/?EbY-kA
```

I am interested to know if backlinks to my site are on indexed pages, so I am not the owner for the sites and I can't use Google Webmaster Tools.
Some information:

- I want to have a clear result because I would automate the search.
- I can't use a 'marker', like a part of the content, because, in some sites, the content is displayed in another page like `jcfrog.com/shaarli/index.php?do=daily&day=20150127` in my example.

Comment: Automating searches like this is against the Google Terms of Service.

Comment: @JohnMueller I know.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine `site:` with search:

[site:jcfrog.com "Le Conseil de l’Europe livre un rapport très critique sur les pratiques de la NSA "](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=cr&ei=xdPdVODAIIPEPPxO#q=site:jcfrog.com%20%22Le%20Conseil%20de%20l%E2%80%99Europe%20livre%20un%20rapport%20tr%C3%A8s%20critique%20sur%20les%20pratiques%20de%20la%20NSA%20%22)

Just type your `site:exampl.com` and add something to the query that's unique for that specific page and check the result if they match. Note the quotes around the string, telling google "Find this string as a whole"

Comment: Yes I use sometimes it but, as you may see, the result is not always correct because you may have a result as 'Indexed' but the real indexed page is 'jcfrog.com/shaarli/index.php?do=daily&day=20150127' not 'http://jcfrog.com/shaarli/?EbY-kA'.

Answer (score 6):

The "problem" with the second URL is its query component (`?EbY-kA`), which Google ignores for the `site:` operator.

You could use the `inurl:` operator in addition:

```
site:jcfrog.com/shaarli/ inurl:EbY-kA
```

However, this does not guarantee that the query component comes directly after the path that is specififed in `site:` (e.g., it would also find pages with URLs like `http://jcfrog.com/shaarli/foooooobar/?EbY-kA`), or that the part in `inurl:` has to be a query component (e.g., it would also find pages with URLs like `http://jcfrog.com/shaarli/foo/EbY-kA`).

---

Another way could be [the `cache:` operator](https://superuser.com/a/669835/151741):

```
cache:http://jcfrog.com/shaarli/?EbY-kA
```

This only works if Google has cached the page in question, so a failure does not necessarily mean that Google has not indexed it.

Comment: 'cache:' operator is a good idea.

Comment: +1 for inurl:

Also worth mentioning is the allinurl: operator which will show you every page indexed in a domain.

Comment: @Motoma: Do you mean `site:` instead of `allinurl:`? AFAIK `allinurl:` is the same as `inurl:`, with the difference that you can specify several keywords (instead of having to repeat `inurl:` for every keyword).